# How do I search MY questions across all SE sites I have profiles on?

Tags: support, search

I can see all my sites and list my questions and other activity but I don't see a trivial way to simply search all *my* various postings on SE sites? When on a bunch of sites it can be hard to find things or remember the tags you might've used.

I'm sure this is easy but I just can't see it?

[image]

I tried searching here in case that was it but it returned no results for something I know I posted about:

[image]